# Regex non exclusive group

Tags: javascript, regex

Do you how can I get this result with Regex? In literal words, I want each groups of successives vowels with the maximum of consonants surrounding them (backward or foreward).

Example :

```
input : alliibaba 

outputs :
[all]
[lliib]
[bab]
[ba]
```

I tried :

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*
```

but it returns distincts groups, so I don't know if it's possible with Regex...

Thanks you for any help.

Comment: You might need a separate regular expression for each group

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew, it will be used in Javascript.

Comment: @mousetail yes I guess... I might need some extra-algo to get that result. I was asking if there was a trick with only Regex... Thanks you.

Comment: I think your output should be `['all', 'lliib', 'ib', 'bab', 'ba']`

Comment: Just wondering but with both options left and right of the vowels wouldn't you also need "iib", "ib", "ba" and "a" as a result? And if not, then why not?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. In litteral words, I want each groups of successives vowels with the maximum of consonants surrounding them (backward or foreward). @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the part of the regex that you want to be made non-exclusive in a lookaround pattern so that it leaves that portion of the search buffer for the next match. Since your rule appears to be that vowels do not overlap between matches while the surrounding consonants can, you can group the consonants after vowels in a lookahead pattern, while putting vowels and any preceding consonants in another capture group, and then concatenate the 2 matching groups into a string for output:

```js
var re = /([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+)(?=([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*))/g;
var s = 'alliibaba';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m)
        console.log(m[1] + m[2])
} while (m);
```

Comment: I don't think you need a lookbehind here, because once consumed that chunk is not needed anymore.

Comment: @georg Not sure what you mean, but the reason why lookbehind is required here is that there is a part of the regex that needs to remain exclusive, the vowels, and the parts that do not consume buffer should surround those that do, and if those parts happen to come before the parts that consume buffer, a lookbehind is required.

Comment: @blhsing: `/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*)([aeiou]+)(?=([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*))/g` seems to work just as fine

Comment: @georg Ah yes you're absolutely right! I forgot that in this case only one of the two groups of consonants around vowels need to be made non-exclusive since they can overlap with only each other but nothing else. Corrected as suggested then. Thanks!

Comment: @georg It returns `llii` instead of `lliib`.

Comment: @blhsing `[bcdfghj-n-tv-z]` is a bit shorter (by 7 characters) and still captures all consonants.  Using it would save 14 characters.